# Smooth scroll jumps back to top of page after processing

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

I have a function using jquery with smooth scroll that scrolls from the top of the page to an anchor pulled from a URL hash.

The scroll works fine, but when it completes, the page resets to the top.

Here is how this is being implemented:

```
 if (hash) { // if hash in the URL

    $('html, body')
      .animate({scrollTop:$(window.location.hash) 
        .offset().top - 200 }, 1000); 
  }
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: make sure to run this after images etc have loaded, so put it inside a `$(window).load(function(){/*your code here*/});`

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The most likely problem is that images and other contents have not yet loaded so the page has not received its final dimensions. This way the initial scroll will point to the wrong position after they have loaded.

A good approach for such cases is to perform the scroll after the content has loaded, so you must wrap your code inside the `$(window).load` method.

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
$(window).load(function(){
  if (hash) { // if hash in the URL

    $('html, body')
      .animate({scrollTop:$(window.location.hash) 
        .offset().top - 200 }, 1000); 
  }
});
```